# SQLAlchemy and python - retrieving non-ascii chars from DB

Tags: python, unicode, sqlalchemy

**My question:** 
Why can't I retrieve non-ascii chars from sqlalchemy db into python?

**In more detail:**
I have an entry with non-ascii char in my sqlalchemy db (Umlaut for example).
When I try to retrieve this entry by using:

```
q=self.session.query(Table_Name).filter(Table_Name.id=='some id')
q.all()
```

I receive the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
```

I solved it by decoding the entries into UTF-8 **before** inserting the entry to the DB.

Yet I wondered - **why** does this error appeared? 
Is there an option to fetch entries already encoded as unicode for example instead of bytechar\ascii into python?

Comment: Is your db UTF-8 and you have # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- in python too?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html), you should specify the encoding in the connection string:

```
e = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test?charset=utf8")
```